# IOS show Html in label with dynamic height

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting a json from webservice that I need to show in tableview. Now the json tag may contain html or string , the label and tableview cell must be of dynamic height . Please help me ...

Comment: are you using autolayout or autoresizing on your app

Comment: use UIWebView Instead of label.

Comment: Did you tried this? http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: If the json response is in normal text then I don't have any problem in resize  . I am using autolayout . I thought webview inside tableview will be slow and may crash for memory so used label with attributed text but struck in dynamic height .

Comment: may this will help you : https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel , but it will put load on memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set estimated height for the tableview.

Using:

tableView?.estimatedRowHeight = 40

After doing this you need to add a label in this cell and set the number of lines to 0.
Give Desired constraints to the label.

Note: Give constraints from the top,left,bottom and right.

Please comment in case you face any issue